# Create a gray scale colormap with colorbar on Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a matrix with 580x580 elements and I want to plot it like a gray colormap (with colorbar indicating the values and axes on the picture indicating pixel values) in a Canvas of a GUI I'm making with TKinter. I know I can do that using the function **imshow(myMatrix, cmap='gray')**, but that requires me to import the pylab library. Is there another way of creating the colormap or, if not, is it possible to show the output of the imshow function on my GUI panel instead of on a new window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to display charts from matplotlib within your tkinter application by setting matplotlib to use the appropriate backend.

```
import matlplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

There are two pretty decent examples of how to do so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073660/python-tkinter-embed-matplotlib-in-gui) and [here.](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/191210/1576303#post1576303)

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I still have to figure out how to insert the colorbar. One last thing: my figure appears after a push a button. However, if I push one more time, it does not put the figure in the same place (instead of the old one basically), but just next to it. Is there any command to do that?

Comment: maupertius: if you're having difficulty with your code, I'd start a new question that includes a small code snippet illustrating the problem. Also, if an answer is helpful, it's courteous to up-vote it and, if it solves your problem, to accept it.

Comment: Wilduck: your answer was VERY helpful, however as a new user I can't vote it up. I haven't accepted your answer because I haven't solved the problem yet

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately, I know more about matplotlib than tkinter, so I won't be too much more use to you. If you need more help, I would ask another question. Post the smallest piece of code that displays the problem you're encountering, the behavior you expect, and what you've tried to do so far.