# Matplotlib Window Size, Title, etc

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I'm new in python and matplotlib. I have a project and I need to create a graphic in a Tkinter GUI a graphic using matplotlib. I found and used this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
menStd =   (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r', yerr=menStd)

womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
womenStd =   (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, womenMeans, width, color='y', yerr=womenStd)


ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax.set_xticklabels( ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5') )

ax.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women') )

def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, '%d'%int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```

But I can't find the way to change the size of the window that appears when I use this code. 
I have already try with this:

```
figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
```

But this only creates another window! Help please!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply replace

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

by:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(num=None, figsize=(16, 12), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
## I changed the fig size to something obviously big to make sure it worked
```

To change the title of the figure window, you can use:

```
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Test')
```

Comment: That helps me a lot!! Do you know how to change the window title and the icon?

Comment: @CesarBorgeMora I edited my answer with how to change the window title. For the icon, I don't know but check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189590/change-icon-in-a-matplotlib-figure-window. Feel free to show your appreciation by accepting my answer :-)

Comment: For me the code above only works after I add the `manager` attribute after `canvas`: `fig.canvas.manager.set_window_title('Test')`.

Comment: @RenéSchwaiger yes it does not work as the answer but as your comment