# How to make matplotlib:pyplot resizeable with the Tkinter window in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tk-toolkit

I am trying to build a grid of frames in each there is a matplotlib figure.
When I resize the window the figure remain with fix size and are not resizing to fit the empty space.
Is there a way to make the figure change its size according to the canvas (hopefully that it does change with the window size)?

[image: before expanding the window]
[image: after expanding the window]

This is how I do the embedding in each frame:

```
self._figure = pyplot.figure(figsize=(4,4))       
self._axes = self._figure.add_subplot(111)
self._canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self._figure, master=self._root)
self._canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1,column=1,rowspan = 4)
```

Comment: If you are doing the embedding correctly, it _should_ behave like any other widget and this is a Tk issue, not an `mpl` issue.

Comment: can you please explain? I added above the embedding code

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/ <- see examples here

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073660/python-tkinter-embed-matplotlib-in-gui). The gist is that there are two parts to making a Tk grid cell grow:

- Use the `sticky` keyword when applying `grid` to your widget, e.g., `widget.grid(..., sticky=Tkinter.NSEW` (Python 2.7) to make `widget` be able to grow in all four directions. See [this documentation for more details](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method).
- Tell the *parent/master* to make the respective column/row grow when resizing by calling `parent.grid_columnconfigure(...)` and/or `parent.grid_rowconfigure(...)` with the desired row, column, and `weight` keyword. E.g., `parent.grid_columnconfigure(col=0, weight=1)` makes the first column take all available space (as long as there are no other columns, or they have not been similary configured). See [the grid_columnconfigure documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_columnconfigure-method) and [the grid_rowconfigure documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_rowconfigure-method) for more details, e.g., about how the weights affect multiple columns/rows.

[This page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) contains many more details about grid layouts.