# Python Tkinter: Embed a matplotlib plot in a widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, tkinter, embed

I have already search for this, for example [Python Tkinter Embed Matplotlib in GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073660/python-tkinter-embed-matplotlib-in-gui) but still can't figure it out. Basically i am trying to plot a fancy graph for a player abilities for a basketball game inside the player window made up with tkinter

```
    self.fig = Figure(figsize=(1.5,1.5))
    self.ax = self.fig.add_axes([0.025,0.025,0.95,0.95],polar=True)
    self.plot_widget = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.top)
    self.ax.grid(False)

    N = 5
    theta = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi/N)
    radii = [self.thisPlayer.rebounds,self.thisPlayer.freeThrows,self.thisPlayer.steal,self.thisPlayer.underRim,self.thisPlayer.distance]
    width = [2*np.pi/(N),2*np.pi/(N),2*np.pi/(N),2*np.pi/(N),2*np.pi/(N)]
    bars = pl.bar(0 , 20,width=2*np.pi, linewidth = 0) + pl.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.2)

    for r,bar in zip(radii, bars):
        bar.set_facecolor( cm.jet(r/20.))
        bar.set_alpha(0.5)

    self.ax.set_xticklabels([])
    self.ax.set_yticklabels([])
    self.plot_widget.show()
    self.plot_widget.get_tk_widget().pack()
```

what happens is that the player window has now the plot widget but the plot is not shown. On the other side, just plotting the abilities not embedded in tkinter works fine. Sorry for my english.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you setup `self.ax`, you need to call `self.ax.bar`, not `pl.bar` to plot the bars in `self.fig`. Here's a runnable example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import Tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.figure as mplfig
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg
pi = np.pi


class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.thisPlayer = Bunch(
            rebounds=20.0,
            freeThrows=5.0,
            steal=5.0,
            underRim=10,
            distance=10)
        self.fig = mplfig.Figure(figsize=(1.5, 1.5))
        self.ax = self.fig.add_axes([0.025, 0.025, 0.95, 0.95], polar=True)
        self.canvas = tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=master)
        self.ax.grid(False)

        N = 5
        theta = np.arange(0.0, 2 * pi, 2 * pi / N)
        radii = [self.thisPlayer.rebounds, self.thisPlayer.freeThrows,
                 self.thisPlayer.steal, self.thisPlayer.underRim,
                 self.thisPlayer.distance]
        width = [2 * pi / (N)] * 5
        bars = (
            # self.ax.bar(0, 20, width=2 * pi, linewidth=0) +
            self.ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.2))
        cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
        for r, bar in zip(radii, bars):
            bar.set_facecolor(cmap(r / 20.))
            bar.set_alpha(0.5)
        self.ax.set_xticklabels([])
        self.ax.set_yticklabels([])
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.canvas.draw()


class Bunch(object):
    """
    http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308
    foo=Bunch(a=1,b=2)
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        self.__dict__.update(kwds)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    tk.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```