# how to terminate program after matplotlib/ tkinter plot is closed

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I have written a python3.x script to make a plot from matplotlib, and tkinter is used for a dialog window to enter a title, and then to browse for the data files to be used.  after a lot of testing everything is working as I want, except that after I close the plot window the program is still running. I have to close the terminal window or reset the kernal in Ipython/jupyter.  Is there a simple way to terminate the program when the pyplot is closed?

Note, I am really new to programming, and a lot of this is stitched together from tutorials and other forum questions.  I am thinking one possible problem is the way that I am backending (matplotlib says that use() is not the preferred way to do it), and maybe a solution could be found by setting up a loop to ask if I want to make another plot.  Another possibility is to put the plot into a tkinter window, but honestly I just taught myself tkinter today as a way to open a browser to select the data files.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tkinter
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


plot_title = ""  #placeholder variable
wavelength = ""  #placeholder variable

def get_plot_title():
    global plot_title 
    plot_title = title_entry.get()
    title_entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    return plot_title

def get_wavelength():
    global wavelength
    wavelength = wavelength_entry.get()
    wavelength_entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    return wavelength

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')

rows = 0
while rows < 10:
    root.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(rows,weight=1)
    rows += 1

title_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Enter TeX style name for plot title.\n (e.g., SrTiO3 would be SrTiO_{3})")
title_label.grid(row=1, column=4)

title_entry = ttk.Entry(root)
title_entry.grid(row=2, column=4)
title_entry.insert(0, 'Enter plot title here')

title_button = ttk.Button(root)
title_button.configure(text='Enter Plot Title', command=get_plot_title)
title_button.grid(row=3, column=4)


title_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Enter diffraction wavelength in Angstroms")
title_label.grid(row=5, column=4)

wavelength_entry = ttk.Entry(root)
wavelength_entry.grid(row=6, column=4)
wavelength_entry.insert(0, 'Enter wavelength here')

wavelength_button = ttk.Button(root)
wavelength_button.configure(text='Enter Wavelength', command=get_wavelength)
wavelength_button.grid(row=7, column=4)

root.mainloop()

##############

Tk().withdraw()

obs_file  = askopenfilename(title = "Select the Observed data file.")
calc_file = askopenfilename(title = "Select the Calcualted data file.")
diff_file = askopenfilename(title = "Select the Difference data file.")
hkl_file  = askopenfilename(title = "Select the hkl data file.")

obs_x, obs_y = np.loadtxt(obs_file, unpack=True)
plt.plot(obs_x, obs_y, 'k.', label='Observed', markersize = 3)

plt.yticks([])

calc_x, calc_y = np.loadtxt(calc_file, unpack=True)
plt.plot(calc_x, calc_y, 'r', label='Calculated')

diff_x, diff_y = np.loadtxt(diff_file, unpack=True)
diff_offset = 100
plt.plot(diff_x, diff_y - diff_offset, color='grey', label='Difference')

rslt_h, rslt_k, rslt_l, rslt_m, rslt_d, rslt_Th2, rslt_lp = np.loadtxt(hkl_file, unpack=True)
rslt_Th2_offset = np.full((len(rslt_Th2), 1), (min(diff_y)-150))

plt.plot(rslt_Th2, rslt_Th2_offset, 'k|', label='hkl')


plt.axis([min(obs_x), max(obs_x), None, None])
plot_title = "$" + str(plot_title) + "$"
plt.text(((max(obs_x)-min(obs_x))/2 ), max(obs_y), plot_title, fontsize=12)
x_axis_label = r'$2\theta (\degree), \lambda = $' + wavelength + ' $\AA $'
plt.xlabel(x_axis_label)
plt.ylabel('Intensity (arb. uints)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Instead of `Tk().withdraw()`, try `root.withdraw()`.

Comment: ...and after you are done with your file dialogs, call `root.destroy()`, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1407700/2454357).

Comment: I have tried replacing the `Tk().withdraw()` as suggested, but when I do I get an error:  "TclError: can't invoke "wm" command: application has been destroyed";  regardless, I dont think this is the issue because I can simply remove the withdraw line to be at the same end spot.  If I add the `root.destroy()` after the `askopenfilename` lines I get the following error: "TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed"

Comment: Ok, it was just a guess. I'm not really an expert on tkinter and the haven't used it together with matplotlib the way you do. What I have done so far is embedding a matplotlib figure in a tkinter window, like it is for instance done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4073660/2454357) and that has always worked. Maybe, if nothing better comes up, you could try adapting your program this way ...

Answer (score -1):

I do this with linux command, it shows all open python processes then i kill it usig its PID

```
ps aux | grep python
kill 1234
```